# Spring Boot with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in unit test needs mandatory @DataJpaTest

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm testing Spring Boot capabilities as a newbie in this area. I have a simple app with basic dependencies.

- sping-boot-starter-parent 1.5.7
- sping-boot-starter
- sping-boot-starter-data-jpa
- sping-boot-starter-test

Then there is simple Application class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.
Then I have a simple DummyService with `@Service` annotation.
Then I have created a simple test DummyServiceTest with one `@Test` method and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest` annotations.

`@SpringBootTest` is the key problem. With spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency and this annotation test requires even `@DataJpaTest` annotation. Without it the framework doesn't solve `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` or `DataSource` or other injection dependencies even if the test doesn't require using data.

Can I suppress it somehow? I'm not any kind of Spring guru so my guess is that there is some simple configuration to handle this problem.

P.S. Ok, back on trees. Even with `@DataJpaTest` that test doesn't solve data dependencies. I tried add `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` and it doesn't work either. I tried add `@Transactional` with the same result. It's a little bit beyond ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using JPA yet, then comment out / remove the dependency from build.gradle until you are using JPA.  You need to define a datasource and other configuration details before the Hibernate and/or JPA configuration will complete successfully.  Every application dependency gets resolved while @SpringApplicationConfiguration code is running, even if your current "hello world" test doesn't require JPA data.

My current unit tests actually have @SpringBootTest commented out.  Here's a simplified view of how things are set up and working in my app's JPA related tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DaemonApplication)
@ActiveProfiles('local')
//@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractJpaTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests { 
    @BeforeTransaction
    public void setupData() throws Exception {
        deleteFromTables('User', 'User_Session', 'User_Handshake');
    }
}
```

and then

```
class UserHandshakeRepositoryIntegrationTest extends AbstractJpaTest {

@Autowired UserHandshakeRepoImpl handshakeRepository;    


@Test
public void testSave() {
    UserHandshake handshake = handshakeRepository.save(new UserHandshake());
    assertThat(handshake.getId(), is(notNullValue()));
}
```